# No Music Showing in Any Music Player

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, music, media-scanner

My Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100 is rooted + 3rd party Jellybean 4.1.2 XXLS6 MIUI rom

Music apps tested: DoubleTwist | Songbird | Google Music

In all of these apps, the music list shows empty.

I have tried:

- Reboot recovery & "fix permissions"
- Launching music files directly from File Explorer (WORKS)

I have a feeling it may be partition or mounts or permissions related. That the apps just can't read the file-system or something?

Can anyone suggest what other things I can try?

Comment: Is there a .nomedia file in your music folders?

Comment: Nope :( Wish it was that easy!

Comment: Please try and clear the data for the media storage app, your music apps and reboot.

Comment: tried this too, no luck

Comment: It appears there is an issue with the media scanner in Samsungs Jellybean base rom.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rooted and have a 3rd party ROM that has not been tested, it might be a bug or a glitch, I would contact the developer.

Comment: This problem this appears to be an issue with the "Media Scanner" function in Samsungs jellybean rom for i9100.